# sbt native packager: cannot locate resource when executable is run

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am working on an application that uses sbt-native-packager with the `akka_application` archetype.

I have a directory structure that looks like:

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
      application.conf
      somePrivateKey.p12
```

Within my code, I have a method to return a file handle to the p12 file

```
def getSomePrivateKey: java.io.File = {
  val cl = this.getClass.getClassLoader
  val fileUrl = cl.getResource("somePrivateKey.p12")
  new java.io.File(fileUrl.getFile())
}
```

When I use this from the command line via `sbt console`, it works perfectly. I can easily work with the file, as expected.

**However**, when I run `sbt stage` and then run the executable it creates, I get a `FileNotFoundException` when trying to open the file.

**How can I tell sbt-native-packager to copy *all* of the files within resources onto the created JAR's ClassPath?** I've read and re-read the sbt-native-packager documentation, tried adding the resource to `Universal`, and it still happens every time. Is there another way I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend against using `getClassLoader` to load resouces. Try always to use relatives paths, like `baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "resources"` or better `"resourceDirectory.value / "your-resources"`.

For *sbt-native-packager* there are several ways to include files.

### #1 default folders

Just place your `somePrivateKey.p12` in on of the following folders

- `src/universal/conf/` For all distributions (zip, deb, msi, etc.)
- `src/linux/conf/` Only for linux distributions
- `src/windows/conf/` Only for windows distributions

You can read about this in more detail at [Adding Configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/GettingStartedApplications/AddingConfiguration.html) and [Generating Files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/GettingStartedApplications/GeneratingFiles.html).

### #2 manually with helper methods

The simple way for one file is very basic

`mappings in Universal += resourceDirectory.value / "somePrivateKey.p12"`

Furthermore you have helpers for directory operations.
See the [Mappingshelper Docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/DetailedTopics/universal.html#mappingshelper) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Update to what Muki wrote above for option #2

```
mappings in Universal ++= directory("src/main/resources")
```

By default this folder should appear in `/opt/docker/resources`